# Choose deprecated python module over custom module?

Tags: python, argparse, python-2.6, optparse

Before I discovered Python modules like `optparse` or `argparse` I wrote my own module to parse command line arguments for the program I am writing. It is suiting my purposes for now and I believe stable with respect to my regression tests. However, I understand the best practice of using Python libraries/modules as well as built-in methods whenever possible.

I am constrained to work in Python 2.6 so I cannot use `argparse` currently. Installing the argparse module isn't a feasible option unfortunately, at least for now.

My question is should I implement `optparse` even though it is deprecated since Python 2.7?

Would the best strategy be to incorporate something to the effect of:

```
try: 
    import argparse
except ImportError:
    import optparse
```

That is something I have implemented with respect to `check_output` from the `subprocess` module. However, then I've resorted to checking the Python system version and writing logic with respect to which module ended up getting successfully imported.

Thanks

Comment: Python 2.6 was EOL in 2013, so six years ago. I understand being tied to old stacks; I deal with some older than that. But when you're confronted with an old stack requirement, you have to accept that you may also discover the library support will force you into some EOL modules as well. I would probably use optparse because it has at least undergone many years of community refinement before becoming deprecated, and wasn't deprecated (from what I can see) for security reasons.

Comment: For commandline processing there isn't one best-practice.  The library (and 3rd party) processors all work with `sys.argv`.  If you are happy with your own parsing, stick with it.  I wouldn't recommend trying to handle both optparse and argparse.  That's just more work.  Don't be afraid of the `optparse` 'deprecation`.  It won't disappear.  There is a `pypi` version of `argparse` - it hasn't received any of the standard updates, but it is still usable (I used it years ago).